# How can I access buttons using string Ids in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Asp.Net. I have a page full of buttons and every button has an id example: btn_1_1, btn_1_2 etc. From the code side I have a loop and I am generating the button's Ids as a string using random numbers, example: "btn_1_1", "btn_1_2" etc. . My question is, how I can use this string value to access the button's properties that have the same ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) method that accepts control's ID as a string.

```
string id = "btn_1_1";
Button btn1 = FindControl(id) as Button;
if (btn1 != null)
{
// Manipulating button's properties
}
```

Just make sure you are calling `FindControl` on the nearest parent of a button, since this method does not perform a recursive search over the controls tree.

Comment: Thanks I used to the following code because I was using a master page. Once again thanks
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
 Response.Write(((Button)cph.FindControl("a")).Text);